# Cannot load csv file header from local disk in neo4j (linux)

Tags: linux, csv, neo4j, local-storage

I have just started with neo4j and this query to import a dataset

```
load csv from "file:/home/goel/rec/data/item.csv" as line 
create (:Movie {id: toInt(line[0]), name: line[1], release_date: line[2]} )
```

gives the error

```
Couldn't load the external resource at: file:/home/goel/rec/data/item.csv
```

What is it missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to close the file path with a double quote. You open with a double quote and try to close with a single quote. It should be:

```
load csv from "file:/home/goel/rec/data/item.csv" as line
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit the neo4j conf file (/etc/neo4j/neo4j.conf)

change the below line

***dbms.directories.import=import***

to

***dbms.directories.import=/home/suyati/Downloads/***

for loading a file from downloads.

In neo4j browser:

***load csv with headers from "file:///1.csv" as row***

(Your file should be there like /home/suyati/Downloads/1.csv)

**Its will works fine.**